# Full URLEncode function in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Could anyone recommend a good open source full URLEncode function for SSJS? I need to encode the full POST body using iso-8859-1 encoding. Platform.Function.UrlEncode() is not doing the job.

Comment: iso-8859-1 isn't the same as URL encoding. iso-8859-1 is just the Latin character set (with diacritics). URL encoding (percent encoding) turns unsafe/reserved/illegal URL characters (colons, slashes, spaces, etc...) into URL entities (%3a, %2f, %20, etc...)

Comment: I do need to encode the URL into the %-like entities. Additionally it needs to follow the ISO-8859-1 standard. Do you know any good functions that could help me achieve that?

Comment: I have not worked in Marketing Cloud or with SSJS, so I'm afraid I can't offer any suggestions. I pretty much only knew enough about character sets and character encoding to leave my other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the AMP script URLEncode() function encoded inline and treated as content.